# Auto-updating version info of C++/CLI project

Tags: c++-cli

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and I have a C++/CLI project I'm using as an interface DLL between a third-party unmanaged library and a C# project.

In this project (as with my C# projects), I'm using a tool called [Build Version Increment](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/releases/view/71360) to automatically increment the version of the project at each build.

The problem is that when the C++/CLI DLL is built, it takes its version information (and other useful details like product name that can be found through right-click > Properties > Details) from a Version Resource. The version incrementing tool I'm using doesn't update this file, so it's sat at v1.0.0.1.

I'd like to know if anyone knows how to automatically update the version resource file (whether from AssemblyInfo.cpp or through a separate version incrementer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this can help you with your problem :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows

Michael

Comment: I finally got round to doing something about this. The version updater you suggested, coupled with reading the AssemblyInfo.cpp file from the project (which is auto updated by the program I already have in place), works a treat. Thanks :)